# Question about turtle_tf transformlistener

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, recently I am learning tf package. I have read the tutorials, but have a small questions concerning the source code of transformlistener, which is: "vel_msg.angular = 4 * atan2(transform.getOrigin().y(), transform.getOrigin().x());" in the line 35. Why dose it need to multiply 4 here? For the aim of more quickly tracking? I know the scale value for keyboard control is 2, but it should be irrelevant to this, as this is calculated from the coordination. Appreciation for any help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12841/question-about-turtle_tf-transformlistener/) by [Mike Gao](https://answers.ros.org/users/1629/mike-gao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2012-02-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe the 4 is just a random scaling factor. A higher value just leads to a quicker rotation but I don't think there is a specific reason for exactly choosing 4.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1